# Are there any items you can combine to make potions, food or equipment?

Tags: deathspank

Aside from combining items for quests and side quests, are there any items you can combine to make potions, food, weapons, et cetera?  I remember obtaining anvils and glass bottles from enemies, but I have no idea what they are for.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess everyone's busy answering starcraft 2 questions :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any thing you can combine to make the weapons and food.

I did find that you can use the anvil to make the cherries fall down off the tree (see this [GameSpot forum post](http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/action/deathspank/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-55715110&pid=991034) for details).

From what I've seen, nobody's been able to figure out what to do with the glass bottles.

Comment: Well thanx for answering, I guess it will remain a mystery